# How to convert APE files to FLAC in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, flac

is there a way to convert a bunch of APE files to FLAC in Linux without altering them in any way? I mean without applying any replaygain, etc..

Comment: `ffmpeg` does support both APE and FLAC, so you can convert. But both formats are lossless, so the actual decoded audio will be identical. I am not sure if you mean that by "not altered in any way".

Comment: this feels woefully unrelated to Linux – FFmpeg runs on pretty much anything modern. So, wouldn't you rather want to ask this on SuperUser.com? Feels like the crowd there would be more familiar with such tools. Also, as dirkt says, lossless audio, so decompress to wav, reencode as flac should always work.

Comment: Should I use `ffmpeg -i input.ape output.flac`?

Comment: This will work.

Answer (score 4):

In the directory with `.ape`/Monkey Audio files:

```shellsession
dir/with/ape$ for i in *ape; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -compression_level 12 "${i%.ape}.flac"; done
```

- The [compression level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836653/ffmpegs-flac-compression-levels-defaults-settings) may be set to whatever you want (0-12), but I typically use the highest as I usually do this in small batches.  NB: This is different than the options for `flac` which is 0-8.
- Prior to conversion, the `.ape` file [may be tested](https://www.bitsgalore.org/2017/01/04/breaking-waves-and-some-flacs#:%7E:text=info%20foo.wav-,Ffmpeg,ffmpeg%20%2Dv%20error%20%2Di%20foo.wav%20%2Df%20null%20%2D,-Mediainfo) with

  ```
  ffmpeg -v warning -i foo.ape -f null -
  ```

  (use `-v error` to see only critical errors) to see if it will decode properly.

If you make a script or shell function (i.e., not an alias), e.g., `ape2flac`, you don't have to find this the next time you find yourself with ape files!

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution provided by @bvargo and it gets the job done, but it uses a for loop to process one file at a time, which is not very efficient. A better approach for converting multiple files is to process them in parallel. This significantly reduces the total conversion time:

```bash
parallel -j12 ffmpeg -i {} -compression_level 12 {.}.flac ::: *.ape
```

- `-j12` specifies the number of parallel jobs